# How to remove the Xcode warning Apple Mach-O Linker Warning 'Pointer not aligned at address

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, warnings

I have a slight issue when build my Xcode project, get tones of warning after update pod. It looks like this

[image]

Already search the whole site here but still no luck. it doesn't affect the project but it is quite annoying. Anyone could help?

Comment: I am also seeing this with firebase analytics since updating to ios 10.3 / Xcode 8.3 beta

Comment: ya, same here. Currently i can only ignore them.

Comment: Firebase has fixed the issue and we are preparing a release.

We also have checked if the warning messages represent a real problem and we found no issue associated with them.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know, do you have any idea when it will be released @GuilhermePuglia?

Comment: We hit some bumps in the road during our validation process, we are working towards launching it earlier next week. I will update this once we launch the new version.

Comment: Version **3.16.0** should fix this. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It probably means their binary file has non-aligned pointer when they compile their code. In those cases the alignment basically defaults to 1 byte and hypothetically might impact performance.
After updating to Xcode 8.3 public release I am still seeing this error, so Google might need to compile their static library with different settings to make it go away.

Comment: That's correct, we're aware of the warnings being generated, and we're working on an update to remove the warnings.

Comment: @RizwanSattar What is the status of the fix?

Comment: The protobuf warnings should be gone as they've updated their pod. If you run pod update, most of the warnings should be gone.  We're preparing a release of firebase tha should get rid of the remainder of the warnings.

Comment: @RizwanSattar running pod update does not remove any of the warnings currently

Comment: @RizwanSattar The new updates to FirebaseCore seems to be breaking things. When running pod update, it installs FirebaseCore 3.6.0 but removes Protobuf, and installs older versions of Firebase, FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseInstanceID and FirebaseMessaging. As a result I am getting compilation errors due to 126 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 between FirebaseAnalytics and FirebaseCore. Is there new update coming to the Firebase pod itself soon?

Comment: Firebase 3.16.0 is out and fixes these issues. Thanks!

Comment: @RizwanSattar Firebase 3.16.0 installed and does not make any difference to the warnings generated.

    ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
    ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_literal_global'
    ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: 'sharedInstance.sharedInstance'

Answer (score 29):

Got this response from firebase support:

> This is a known issue with Xcode 8.3 beta, so it might be a beta thing
>   and Xcode being extra verbose.  It works well though with 8.2.1 so I
>   recommend temporarily use it to avoid the warnings or ignore the
>   warnings on 8.3 beta if it does not affect your app.

Comment: It's a problem in xcode 8.3 release.  How embarrassing for google.  Firebase already causes notification warnings when uploading your app.  I'm going to ditch it.  I'm sick of them not having their act together.

Comment: Pretty ridiculous. It's extra frustrating because just using the Google SignIn pod automatically includes all the (unwanted) Firebase stuff - wish I could ditch it too!

Comment: Yes just now updated my Xcode there are many warning about that google and firanalytics. Is there any release about that pods?

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is Google-specific; I am getting the same warnings when using the D compiler, which (as far as I can tell) has nothing to do with Firebase.

Comment: Some comment from Apple and/or Google about the issue would be, fair.

Comment: Create a ticket at firebase. I did.

Comment: @michal Link to your ticket so we can star it instead of creating duplicates.

Comment: Hey folks, just wanted to let you know that the Firebase team is aware of the warnings generated in Xcode 8.3 and we're working to remove them. This comes down to a compilation issue, and should not cause any problems in your code, though it's still ugly, and we shouldn't be generating any warnings.

Comment: Happens to me now with 33 warning.

Comment: I have 39 warnings in my project because of this, this makes my OCD unhappy. Does anyone (maybe someone from Firebase or Google) have a warning suppression fix for this at least?

Comment: 32 similar warnings on my side, but also, my app is now broken: network connections start but don't finish and eventually the app completely freezes, probably on some deadlock. It may be unrelated to this issue, but then that's the only compilation problem I have. The same code runs fine when compiled with Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: A slightly related "protobuf" framework (also from Google) which also caused a lot of warnings seems to have been updated recently - the warnings are gone. Hooray. Now only Firebase warnings remain for me.

Comment: Huh, I take back the part about the app being broken in relation to those warnings that I mention above, the app is broken by Xcode 8.3 even with an older version of the Firebase framework that doesn't generate the warnings.

Comment: Same like 39 warnings in my project when after adding firebase to my project through pod. I am just tired of using firebase, it takes too much time to link firebase with google admob, and then same like adding connecting each of admob(banner advertisements and as well as interstitial) again and again and these efforts takes too much time where as time = money, can any one suggest google team to make their process easy for developers instead of time consuming and after spending too much time there is still 39 issues...

Comment: The fixed pod should be available anytime today. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @AniV Is this going to be an update to the general Firebase pod? So this one: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase. No update yet if so..

Comment: Ok it's fixed.  I hope that notification issue when uploading an app is fixed as well.

Comment: @ChrisVanBuskirk Nope it is still not fixed

Comment: @jakedunc The notification issue?

Comment: @ChrisVanBuskirk Yeah I still get an email about "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" when I don't have Push Notifications in my app..

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed in Firebase 3.16.0 (Firebase Core 3.6 + Firebase Analytics 3.8.0)

Comment: It's true, a pod update fixed it: 
`Installing Firebase 3.16.0 (was 3.15.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 3.8.0 (was 3.7.0)
Installing FirebaseCore 3.6.0 (was 3.5.2)`

Comment: @aramusss How Can I update to the new Firebase SDK, is that what I put in my pod

Comment: Use pod update in the command line (search on google if any questions) :)

Answer (score 6):

guys, it is all fixed now. Tested it all myself on two projects. You got to go to the correct directory of your project so that your pod spec file is visible to your command line commands, run

```
pod update
```

and see it all fixed and working properly!

Comment: Happy to hear that !

Answer (score 2):

These problems are addressed, and likely fixed, with release 3.16.0.