# Apple Mach -O Linker (Id) Warning in Xcode 8.3 release

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, xcode8, firebase-analytics

I have just updated my Xcode to 8.3 release.

And now I'm getting many warnings like: **"Pointer not aligned at address.."** from my pods.

[image]

I see **FirebaseAnalytics** and **FirebaseCore** pods trigger this issue.

What should I do in this case?

> Fixed with 'pod update' right now.

Comment: Also reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268117/how-to-remove-the-xcode-warning-apple-mach-o-linker-warning-pointer-not-aligned

Comment: Nothing for the moment. This is going to be fixed most probably in a future release.