# Apple Mach-O Linker and Protobuf multiple warnings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, warnings

My app is connected to Firebase databases. Yesterday all was working perfectly, the day after I found 240 warnings like this:

[image]

I also have problems with Protobuf :

[image]

Comment: someone asked same question before, check this our http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268117/how-to-remove-the-xcode-warning-apple-mach-o-linker-warning-pointer-not-aligned/42448144

Comment: ok thanks for help